# How does gdb interpret `main` when no debug symbols loaded?

Tags: c, gdb

```
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/ctest/printf...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400498 <main+0>:    push   %rbp
0x0000000000400499 <main+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040049c <main+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

How does gdb interpret `main` when no debug symbols loaded?

Answer (score 2):

GDB doesn't "interpret" `main`.

If your question is "how does GDB know where main is", the answer is: "because its address is in the symbol table" (see output from `nm /root/ctest/printf`). On UNIX (unlike Windows) one doesn't need debug symbols to have function and global variable names in the executable (or shared library) -- they are kept by default (to make debugging easier). If you wanted to hide your `main`, you could run `strip printf` to remove it (and all other symbols) from the executable.

For your second question, `main` isn't mangled because it has `extern "C"` linkage. It must have that linkage so it can be called from assembly (it is called by the C runtime startup, usually `crt1.o`).

Comment: I've two questions:1.why is there still `main` symbol when debug symbols aren't loaded?2.why the name `main` isn't manglinged away?

Answer (score 0):

`main` isn't a debug symbol, so it isn't stripped.  It has external linkage, so it is preserved unless an explicit strip or link command removes it.  It isn't mangled because on most platforms, there is no name mangling in the C ABI (except maybe for appending an underscore or similar).

The linker and other tools are able to determine what symbols are debug symbols and which are extern, or private, etc, because they are marked differently in the symbol table.  For example, on Mac OS X, we might see something like this:

```
                 U _constantFromAnotherModule
0000000000000018 T _externFunction
0000000000000410 s _privateInt
0000000000000000 t _staticFunction
```

The different letters in the middle column, before the symbol names, indicate different types of linkage, and they are treated differently by the tools.

Even if the symbols *are* mangled, tools often know how to undo the mangling, so a debugger should be able to find a function name in a symbol table even if it has been mangled, so long as it was built by tools compatible with the debugger.  Beyond that, `main( )` in C++ has C linkage, and follows the platform's C ABI, so it is typically not mangled.

Comment: I've two corresponding questions:1.How does the link judge whether a symbol is debug symbol or not?2.So for c++ ABI,`disas main` won't work?

Comment: What's the difference between debug symbols and other symbols?Aren't all symbols for debugging purpose?Say,it still works if you `strip` its symbols.

Comment: @kernel: No, all symbols are not for debugging.  Symbols (or some other form of bookkeeping) are required for a linker to function.  None of the symbols in my example are debugging symbols.

Comment: but the final executable don't need a linker to function,right?